# How to replace text in html content but not style attributes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I want to highlight the text in html content without effecting the style attributes using jquery.

I have html content in a div and i want to highlight the search keyword in that particular div content but it should not replace style attributes.

```
    <div class='resume_details_list'>
     <p style="margin:0pt;">
        Over 7.8+ years of experience <span style="font-size:10pt;">complete development life cycle - Requirement, Program design, Coding, Testing, Deployement,Stylesheet, margin Help and Documentation with Database Structure design. Having Onsite/Offshore work experience.</span>
     </p>
    </div>
```

Now i want to highlight the keyword "style" or "margin" And for that i am using the below code

```
var selector = ".resume_details_list";
var searchTerm = 'style';
var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
    if (searchTerm === "&") {
           searchTerm = "&amp;";
           searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
    }

    $(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
}
```

Now its highlighting the text wherever "style" appears, but it's breaking my html content. But i don't want to replace the style tag or css attributes inside style.

Please help me to get my issue resolved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just replace `$(selector).html($(selector).html()` with `$(selector).html($(selector).text()`.

Comment: Why don't you use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)?

Answer (score 2):

I have changed my regular expression to

```
var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('(?![^<]+>)' + searchTerm , 'gi');
```

The RegEx checks for text that does not belong to an HTML tag. It will check only text. Its working fine for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your may perhaps use this *regex* `searchTerm + '(?![=\\-;:"_\'])'`.

```js
var selector = ".resume_details_list";
var searchTerm = 'style';
var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm + '(?![=\\-;:"_\'])', "ig");
var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
if (matches !== null && matches.length > 0) {
    if (searchTerm === "&") {
           searchTerm = "&amp;";
           searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
    }
    $(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='resume_details_list'>
    <p style="margin:0pt;">
        Over 7.8+ years of experience <span style="font-size:10pt;">complete development life cycle - Requirement, Program design, Coding, Testing, Deployement,Stylesheet, margin Help and Documentation with Database Structure design. Having Onsite/Offshore work experience.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this will not work, if the search term is something else in a html-tag, like only a part of an attribute name, the tag name or an attribute value or part of this. your regex must make sure not to match anything between < >. tried to make one, but failed :/

Comment: Hi Siam, thanks for your response. If we try with the keyword 'margin' its not working & its appending style attributes.

Comment: @Hareesh check updated answer. hope it works fine now :-)

Comment: @Siam It will work for some scenarios like 'margin-top', 'margin-left' attributes but it won't work for 'margin' :)

Comment: @Hareesh yes it will. did you check the updated answer *(regex)*? :)